# Is it possible to dynamically create these jQuery click handlers?

Tags: jquery, function, dynamic

I need to create click handlers for several HTML buttons that control an image gallery.  Each of the buttons in the HTML receive a class that indicates which function to perform - such as step forward or step backward.  I also need to create these handlers for multiple galleries on the same web page.

This is the "hard coded" version. Is it possible to create a dynamic function(s) to replicate this working example below?

```
$('.gallery0_stepForward').on('click', function() {
    gallery_changeImage(0, 1);    // step gallery 0 forward 1 image
    gallery_stopAutoTimer(0);     // stop the automatic slide show
});
```

I have attempted something like this:

```
for (i=0;i<5; i++){   // 5 galleries in this example

    var target = ".gallery" + i + "_stepForward";
    var fnName = "stepForward" + i;

    function setFunc ( fnName ) {
        this[ fnName ] = function() {
                console.log('hello ' + fnName);
                gallery_changeImage(i, 1);
        gallery_stopAutoTimer(i);
           };
    }

    $(target).on('click', fnName);
}
```

The system of attaching classes to the HTML must remain. The function "gallery_changeImage(val,val)" must remain as there are multiple lines of code in that function. Thank you.

Comment: Could you tell me why this was voted down to help me ask questions correctly in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to tell exactly what you are doing, with so little code, but I would suggest attaching an event to the parent container, listening to clicks on your images, and using `data-*` attributes on your elements to control behaviour. For example :

#### HTML

```
<div class="image-gallery" data-gallery-index="0">
  <img src="...">
  <img src="...">
  <!-- more images -->
</div>
<div class="image-gallery" data-gallery-index="1">
  <img src="...">
  <img src="...">
  <!-- more images -->
</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(function () {
  $('.image-gallery').on('click', 'img', function () {
    // the `this` keyword is the clicked <img> element
    var imgGalleryIndex = $(this).closest('.image-gallery').data('gallery-index');

    // step gallery imgGalleryIndex forward 1 image
    gallery_changeImage(imgGalleryIndex, 1);    

    // stop the automatic slide show
    gallery_stopAutoTimer(0);
  });
});
```

Using this technique, you donn't need to add click handlers directly to images and it will handle click on any children of your gallery containers as JS events bubble and this is a jQuery feature.

Comment: I can see how this technique will work for me, it does require some re-work on my end but that is on me.  Back to the original approach / question, is it possible to write the functions dynamically?  What is incorrect in my above attempt?  Is that even viable?  -if you don't mind.  Thank you.

Comment: @marksjack, in your approach, for one, you are setting `this[ fnName ]` and is totally irrelevant, unless you really want to reuse `this[ fnName ]` somewhere else? (Note that the actual function is *still* anonymous--i.e. has no name--). Secondly, if you gallery has several hundreds of images (or if you dynamically add/remove images), then you need to sync the dynamically added events. Added a "future" event on the parent container let's you avoid all this, is cleaner and does not require creating non generic CSS classes (which is the role of the ID attribute, not the CSS class name!).

Comment: @marksjack, also, using `data-*` attributes is more sementic as it describe what is the purpose of the value, as opposed to `gallery0_foo` which does not tell what's the `0` for... or even if it's actually required anywhere.